# navigationbar color same as uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

i've created a UIView Which i would like to have the same color as the navigationbar.

The color of the navigationbar is stated in appdelegate using following code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.353 green:0.259 blue:0.463 alpha:1]];
```

And the UIView is as following:

```
[self.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.353 green:0.259 blue:0.463 alpha:1]];
```

Even though it is the same UIColor the colors seem to be different. How can i make the UIView the same color as navigationBar?

Comment: You need to make sure all the layer in the NavigationBar is set to clear as default, I think it blends together with that color, so it looks a bit different. The default color of the UINavigationBar is black.

Comment: Is this for iOS6 and below or iOS7 and above? If its the latter you will want to subclass UIToolbar to reproduce the opacity effect in the UINavigationBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the bar is translucent, so it has a different color. Do this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```